# Creating a notepad in java, color change, font change, print, url, hyperlink

Tags: java, notepad

I am creating a notepad in java for a class assignment. I have created the text box with the File, Edit, Print, Help buttons with drop downs to do various options, I need help with the color change, font change, sent to printer and the hyperlinks under help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class MyMenuFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private TextArea textArea = new TextArea("", 0,0,TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
    // first, create a MenuBar item
    private MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    private Menu file = new Menu();
    private Menu edit = new Menu();
    private Menu print = new Menu();
    private Menu help = new Menu();
    // File objects
    // open option
    private MenuItem open = new MenuItem();
    //  save option
    private MenuItem save = new MenuItem();
    // close option!
    private MenuItem close = new MenuItem();

    // Edit objects
    // color option
    private MenuItem color = new MenuItem();
    // font option
    private MenuItem font = new MenuItem();
    // print object
    private MenuItem printSend= new MenuItem();
    // help objects
    private MenuItem about= new MenuItem();
    private MenuItem home=new MenuItem();

    public MyMenuFrame() {
        // set the initial size of the window
        this.setSize(600, 400);
        // set the title of the window
        this.setTitle("MyNotepad");
        // set the default close operation
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // set a default font for the TextArea
        this.textArea.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic", Font.BOLD, 12));
        // this is why we didn't have to worry about the size of the TextArea!
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // the BorderLayout bit makes it fill it automatically
        this.getContentPane().add(textArea);

        // add our menu bar into the GUI
        this.setMenuBar(this.menuBar);
        this.menuBar.add(this.file);
        this.menuBar.add(this.edit);
        this.menuBar.add(this.print);
        this.menuBar.add(this.help);

        // create file drop down menu
        this.file.setLabel("File");

        // create open option
        this.open.setLabel("Open");
        //action listener to know when it's been clicked
        this.open.addActionListener(this);
        // keyboard shortcut
        this.open.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_O, false));
        // add it to the "File" menu
        this.file.add(this.open);

        // create save option
        this.save.setLabel("Save");
        //action listener to know when it's been clicked
        this.save.addActionListener(this);
        // keyboard shortcut
        this.save.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_S, false));
        // add it to the "File" menu
        this.file.add(this.save);

        // create close option
        this.close.setLabel("Exit");
        // action listener to know when it's been clicked
        this.close.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_X, false));
        // keyboard shortcut
        this.close.addActionListener(this);
        // add it to the "File" menu
        this.file.add(this.close);

        // create edit drop down menu
        this.edit.setLabel("Edit");
        this.edit.addActionListener(this);
        this.color.setLabel("Color");
        this.font.setLabel("Font");
        this.color.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_C,false));
        // color and font change buttons added
        this.edit.add(this.color);
        this.edit.add(this.font);

        // print menu
        this.print.setLabel("Print");
        this.print.addActionListener(this);
        this.printSend.setLabel("Send to Printer");
        // send to printer button and shortcut keys added
        this.print.add(this.printSend);
        this.printSend.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_P,false));

        // help menu
        this.help.setLabel("Help");
        this.about.setLabel("About");
        this.home.setLabel("Visit Home");
        this.about.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_A,false));
        this.home.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_H,false));
        this.help.addActionListener(this);
        // about and homepage buttons added
        this.help.add(this.about);
        this.help.add(this.home);

    }
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        // if the source of the event was our "close" option
        if (e.getSource() == this.close)
            this.dispose(); // dispose all resources and close the application

            // if the source was the "open" option
        else if (e.getSource() == this.open) {
            JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser(); // open up a file chooser (a dialog for the user to browse files to open)
            int option = open.showOpenDialog(this); // get the option that the user selected (approve or cancel)
            // NOTE: because we are OPENing a file, we call showOpenDialog~
            // if the user clicked OK, we have "APPROVE_OPTION"
            // so we want to open the file
            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                // clear the TextArea before applying the file contents
                this.textArea.setText("");
                try {
                    // create a scanner to read the file
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(open.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                    // while there's still something to read
                    while (scan.hasNext())
                        this.textArea.append(scan.nextLine() + "\n"); // append the line to the TextArea
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { // catch any exceptions
                    //write to the debug console
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        //if the source of the event was the "save" option
        else if (e.getSource() == this.save) {
            //open a file chooser
            JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser();
            // similar to the open file, only this time we call
            int option = save.showSaveDialog(this);
            // showSaveDialog instead of showOpenDialog
            // if the user clicked OK
            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    // create a buffered writer to write to a file
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                    // write the contents of the TextArea to the file
                    out.write(this.textArea.getText());
                    // close the file stream
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { //catch any exceptions
                    //write to the debug console
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        else if(e.getSource()==this.color){


        }

        else if(e.getSource()==this.font){
            JFileChooser font= new JFileChooser();
        }

        else if(e.getSource()==this.printSend){
            JFileChooser printSend= new JFileChooser();
        }

        else if(e.getSource()==this.about){
            JFileChooser about= new JFileChooser();
        }

        else if(e.getSource()==this.home){
            JFileChooser home= new JFileChooser();
        }


    }
```

}

public class MyMenuFrameTest {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyMenuFrame notePad = new MyMenuFrame();
    notePad.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

These are the parameters my professor has specified.
a. The title of the frame is “MyNotepad”. 
b. Create and add border layout. 
c. Create a text area to display contents. Add the text area to the center of the border layout. 
d. Create a menu bar. 
e. Create a file menu. Set mnemonic for file menu. It is “F”. File menu includes three menu items. 
f. Add a separator between each menu item in the file menu.

i. Open 1. Add a short cut for the menu item. It is ctrl+O. 
a. Use this syntax:  MenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStr oke('O', CTRL_DOWN_MASK)); 
2. When a user clicks it (an action event occurs) a file chooser is created, and an open dialog box is opened. The user selects a text file to open it and then clicks “Open” or the user can click on “Cancel”. Use try block with resources. (Hint: add catch block automatically, click add catch clause).

ii. Save 1. Add a short cut for the menu item. It is ctrl+S. 
2. When a user clicks it (an action event occurs) a file chooser is created, and a save dialog box is opened. The user writes the name of text file to save it and then clicks “Save” or the user can click on “Cancel”. User try block with resources. (Hint: add catch block automatically, click add catch clause).

iii. Exit 1. Add a short cut for the menu item. It is ctrl+X. 
2. When a user clicks it (an action event occurs), it terminates the application. g. Create edit menu. Set mnemonic for file menu. It is “D”. Edit menu includes two menus: Color and Font. h. Add a separator between each sub menu.

i. Create color menu. Set mnemonic for file menu. It is “C”. i. Create change color menu item. Add a short cut for the menu item. It is ctrl+C.

ii. When a user clicks change color, a color chooser is opened, and the user selects a color. By default, red color is selected. Then, the color of the text is changed.

j. Create font menu. Set mnemonic for file menu. It is “F”. 
i. This menu includes three radio button menu items: Times New Roman, Arial, Serif. (Hint: you also need a button group). When a user selects one of these fonts (an action event occurs), the font of the text will change. Set font size as 20.
ii. This menu includes also two check box menu items: Bold, Italic. A User can select both, only bold one, italic one, or unselect any of them (an item event occurs). Based on the user selection, set the font. (Hint: if one of them is unselected, set the font as plain). Set font size as 20.
iii. Add a separator between radio button menu items and check box menu items.

k. Create Print menu. Set mnemonic for print menu. It is “P”. i. Printer menu includes one menu item: Send to Printer. Add a short cut for the menu item. It is ctrl+P.

ii. When a user clicks it (an action event occurs), display an Option Dialog. Display the message in the figure. If the user clicks “Ok”, display a message dialog box (set information icon). Display the message in the figure. If the user clicks cancel, make the current frame as visible.

l. Create a help menu. Set mnemonic for help menu. It is “H”. m. Help menu includes two menu items: About, Visit Homepage. Add a separator between these menu items.

i. Create a menu item which is about. Add a short cut for the menu item. It is ctrl+A.

1. When a user clicks it (an action event occurs), display a show message dialog box. Display the message shown in the figure. Display information icon.

ii. Create a menu item which is visit homepage. Add a short cut for the menu item. It is ctrl+V. 
1. When a user clicks it (an action event occurs), the user will be navigated to http://www.microsoft.com. 
2. For the navigation, create a static method (copy it):

public static void openWebpage (String urlString) {
 try {         Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new             URL(urlString).toURI());     }
 catch (Exception e) {         e.printStackTrace();     } }

Then in the action performed method, call this static method and provide the url String.

n. When it is necessary, import the necessary classes and interfaces. 
o. Set frame as 600*400.

Comment: You won't find anyone who writes the code for you, here. Please post questions about concrete programming problems, and **not** a list of "tasks" you need solved.

Comment: I completely understand that, I was really asking for a nudge in the right direction. Thank you for your time with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, a JTextArea uses one font and one color.  Use [JTextPane](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) instead.

As for your font and color menu actions, use the JTextPane’s [getStyledDocument()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#getStyledDocument%28%29) method.

You’ll need to create an AttributeSet for each action.  If you look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/AttributeSet.html), you’ll see many implementing classes.  Among them is [SimpleAttributeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/SimpleAttributeSet.html), which is sufficient for your needs.  Rather than setting its attributes directly, use the methods of [StyleConstants](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/StyleConstants.html).

Printing is as simple as calling the inherited [print()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#print%28%29) method.

Needless to say, you should remove the use of JFileChooser from any action which doesn’t actually need to read or write a file.

Comment: thank you I almost have it figured out now, I still cant get the font to change but everything else is running smooth.